Looker Studio Line Chart: How to Retain Abbreviated Format on Y-Axis After Changing Metric Title?
I am using Looker Studio to create a line chart based on my data. When I use the default chart metric title, the y-axis displays numbers in an abbreviated format (e.g., '1K' for 1,000). However, if I change the chart metric title, the y-axis formatting changes and all numbers are displayed in full, which clutters the chart.
Is there a way to keep the abbreviated format on the y-axis even after changing the metric title? Any insights or steps to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if any additional information is needed. Thank you!
a way to keep the abbreviated format on the y-axis even after changing the metric title
